# 3DS Street Pass Not Working

Tags: technical-issues, streetpass

Lately the Street Pass feature of the 3DS has not been working for me. A coworker and I will both have our 3DSs, at work, next to each other, with the wifi on and street pass never connects. Sometimes turning the wifi on and off will cause it to connect properly.

Anyone know if there are any better solutions? I'm worried I'm missing random street passes out there because most of the time it requires me to toggle the wifi.

Comment: Are both 3DS flaps closed? They both need to be "sleeping" (flap closed) to reliably perform a street pass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just wanted to add aside from the correct answer from Joe, I too have been having issues with the street pass function not working 100% of the time. When I first received my 3ds I would go over to my brothers house and it would instantly light up, but tonight when I went over it took a while and a little fiddling with to react. My honest opinion would be that it is still working out the little bugs and most likely be honed to perfect with a ninja update. Still a lot of features for this system to pop up.

My advice would be to just set the two down next to each other and let them sort it out.

Also, 100% correct on the "cooldown" for the data swapping, 8-10 hours. Although I haven't tried getting one swap, going out to get a different one, and then trying to swap again. That might be worth an experiment. Maybe you can't get the same data unless you get different data.. following me? Alright I'll go crazy professor laugh over here by myself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea, i think they are still working through some issues, because, following all the steps and doing everything the way it seems to be intended to work. i.e. only expecting to sync once per day, being in close vicinity to each other, it doesn't seem to work 100% of the time. We have also guessed that maybe all the wifi networks in our office are somehow attributing to its inconsistency. We work in a technology heavy building and there are tons of access points around.

Comment: Note that a 3DS which is sleeping while playing a *standard* DS game (such as New Super Mario Bros) will not StreetPass.

Answer (score 6):

Streetpass requires some hours - about 8-10, but it doesn't seem to be entirely consistent - between connections with the same 3DS. My wife and I both have 3DSs and they tend to sync during the night and once or twice during the day. I would expect to sync at most once a day in an office.

<del>Streetpass will not work if your 3DSs are open.</del> Several times I swear my Streetpass has synced immediately on closing my 3DS but not before. However, today during a Streetpass event I synced with three people while I was getting puzzle pieces from eight others. Still, having your 3DS closed seems to increase the chances of connecting successfully.

Toggling your wifi might also be slowing it down, as the first thing the 3DS does when the wifi comes back up is to connect to the Internet, not look for Streetpasses.

Comment: 8-10 hours?! Shouldn't StreetPass work within seconds, considering its name? (Not saying you're wrong, just that the statistic is pretty surprising to me.)

Comment: I think that 8-10 is the time that data is exchange between the same two 3DS. If my 3DS synchronize with yours, then even if we meet again in the 8-10 hours, they won't exchange StreetPass data.

Comment: Yes, Sylvain has the right idea. My 3DS exchanges almost immediately after my wife gets home from work, for example, but then not again until the middle of the night.

Comment: Silly me, I didn't read the "between connections" part and thought that's the time it took to transfer the actual data. Whoops.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just change the Mii you streetpass with. It sometimes works :D

Answer (score 1):

I find sometimes its fickle. I visit a friend once a week, and sometimes our 3DSes see each other right away, sometimes not. I think its best to have it closed and in the main menu, or sometimes in the Mii Plaza. I think you can Streetpass while you have a game suspended, but it may not work as well.
On the other hand, my roommate has a 3DS. If I don't remember to use them before the time resets, their Mii will just tag me multiple times in 1 pass (though I can only use them for games once.)